# Doubly edge-contraction critical graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Is there a simple undirected, connected, non-complete graph $G=(V,E)$ with at least $2$ edges, such that the following condition holds?

> > Whenever you contract $1$ or $2$ edges, the resulting graph has chromatic number strictly smaller than $\chi(G).$

**EDIT**: Added connectedness, otherwise $K_n$ plus an isolated point is an uninteresting solution for $n>2$.

Comment: Do you allow triangles in your graph? If yes --- what happens to the edge $ac$ when you contract $ab$ and $bc$? Does it disappear or turn into a loop?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov When considering colouring problems, it is customary to suppress parallel edges and loops when taking minors.  Note that if the chromatic number always goes down when we contract *any* number of edges, then the graph must be a complete graph (if Hadwiger's Conjecture is true).