# Contracting 2 edges

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

This is a weakening of [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247738/doubly-edge-contraction-critical-graphs) question.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple, undirected, connected graph, let $n=|V|$ and assume $n\geq 3$. Suppose that whenever you contract $2$ edges, the chromatic number decreases.

Does this imply that $G$ contains a clique of $n-1$ vertices?

Comment: Something interesting I noticed, not sure if it helps:

A graph has a clique of $n - 1$ vertices if and only if its complement has no two edges without vertices in common and no triangles. For a graph as you describe, any subgraph given by removing a triangle or by removing two edges without vertices in common must also have decreased chromatic number.

Comment: Interesting comment, thank you! I don't quite see yet how to use this for answering the question, but maybe there is a way.